# Cross Domain AJAX Request is not working on IE10

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I sent ajax request from 'sub.example.com' to 'www.example.com/api/lists'(yes, it is subdomain), but it's not working only IE.  It's working on FF, Chrome, Safari and other mobile browser.

Error Message - SEC7120 : 
Origin http://sub.example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

My server setting is

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

I tried two ways.  first, jQuery.ajax();

```
$.ajax({
  url : 'http://www.example.com/api/lists',
  type : 'GET',
  dataType : 'JSON',
  cache : false,
  crossDomain : true
}).success(function(data){
  // do something
});
```

and navtive javascript.

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.example.com/api/lists');
 xhr.send();
```

both of them not working only IE10 Browser.(not tested lt IE10 yet)

Comment: Can you also post the contents of the response header so we can make sure your PHP code is correctly setting the header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the space between the colon and the asterisk.

Change

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *');
```

to

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Internet Explorer is quite unflexible when it comes to correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You may be facing an [IE10 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188500/why-is-ie-10-refusing-to-send-post-data-via-jquery-ajax), and the ticket on JQuery has been [closed](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12790) as this is an issue with IE10 itself.

The 'workaround' at the moment is to set compatibility mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" >
```

It is also worth reading through the post I've linked to.