# AngularJS Web API - IE does not post Form body

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api, internet-explorer-11

When I do an **http post** in angular JS (using IE 11), the `OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext` form body does not contain any data at `ValidateClientAuthentication`.

Note that this works perfectly well with Chrome and Firefox. If I open the debugger and switch to **IE 9**, It works but when I close the debugger, it switches to **IE 11** and stops working.

Any ideas appreciated!

```
//sample code    
var data = "grant_type=password&username=john&password=mYpass10&client_id=self"

this.$http.post('/token', 
    data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } })
    .success(function(response: any) {})
    .error(function(err, status) {});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would adding the below to your page fix the issue?

`<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" >`

This is apparently a bug Microsoft was looking into. See more info:

http://blog.yorkxin.org/posts/2014/02/06/ajax-with-formdata-is-broken-on-ie10-ie11/

[Why is IE 10 Refusing to send POST data via jQuery $.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188500/why-is-ie-10-refusing-to-send-post-data-via-jquery-ajax)