# Angular manual bootstrapping does not works on IE 10

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, internet-explorer-10, bootstrapping

Hi Developed SPA using AngularJS.
In my application, I'm using manual bootstrapping:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            var idsid;
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://myServer/MyApp/getUser.aspx',
                async: false,
                jsonpCallback: 'getUserIdentity',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    //alert("error"+status + " error value: "+error);//todo - remove alert, write to log
                },
                success: function (response) {
//                   do something with response
                    angular.bootstrap(document, ["MyApp"]);
                }
            });
        });</script>
```

This code works great on Chrome, Firefox and even on IE11.
When I'm trying to run it using IE10, I'm getting the next error:
SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier 
08dcf8d5.scripts.js, line 4 character 1272
SCRIPT5022: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'MyApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

`http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/nomod?p0=MyApp
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'MyApp'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.15%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%MyApp
angular.js, line 3745 character 9`

I'm using grunt to prepare my code before publish it into production (IIS Server) and the weird thing is that when I'm trying to run my app with local server ('grunt serve'), IE 10 open it without any issues.

I assume that something in the "grunt build" operation, prevent IE10 from using the application.
Just to remind - in Chrome, Firefox and IE11 my application works fine (on local and server versions).

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the following parameters:

```
cache: false,
crossDomain: false
```

**References**

- [CORS for XHR in IE10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc288060)
- [Jquery Ajax call works in all browser except ie 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101729/1113772)
- [crossDomain in IE9 is interpreted wrong](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12097)
- [jQuery Core: Ticket #8283: Built-in support for XDomainRequest](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283?format=rss)
- [A Look at Asynchronous Script Downloads](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonbox/archive/2011/08/18/a-look-at-asynchronous-script-downloads.aspx)
- [Compatibility Changes in IE11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bg182625)
- [HTML Spec: Obsolete Features - document.all](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#dom-document-all)
- [Internet Explorer 11: Don’t call me IE](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/07/02/internet-explorer-11-dont-call-me-ie/)